# How to link Open CV builded with mingw with Python3

Tags: python, c++, opencv, msbuild

I first installed opencv and opencv-contrib from below link

```
https://github.com/opencv
```

Then I tried cmake with visual c++ but it failed because it cannot find the file "MSBuild.exe" even though I have Visual C++2017 installed in my PC.Then I tried it with mingw makefile and it generated files sucessfully.But to my suprise there is no .pyd or any python linked file.

I am now clueless how to go further linking it with python3. :(

Comment: ***it cannot find the file "MSBuild.exe" even though I have Visual C++2017 installed in my PC*** You should be able to fix your path so that it is found.

Comment: ***Then I tried it with mingw makefile and it generated files sucessfully.But to my suprise there is no .pyd or any python linked file.*** I think you need to enable python support when configuring with CMake.

Comment: I think it is already enabled. I have uploaded that screenshot https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OvCdK159Dmm3-UhMLcyM5ZMm-JANdzg6

Comment: I don't have any MSBuild.exe file in my system instead I have MSBuildTaskHost.exe

Comment: when on windows I would not even try wasting time on building well-known libraries, why not search internet for "python windows binaries", download a suitable one, pip install that pre-built wheel and be done with it.

Comment: This is because I need a function cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer() which is in opencv_config